# MakerDAO MKR Withdrawal. Continuous Approval Voting

Tags: tokens, voting, makerdao, governance

When I want to vote on some proposals, I need to lock some MKR tokens. Does it mean that I withdraw my MKR tokens, then the result of voting may change even after it has finished?

Does Continuous Approval Voting mean endless voting?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that I withdraw my MKRs then the result of voting may change even after it has finished?

If the voting for a specific proposal has finished (and has become the governing proposal), then it will be executed on chain. It will not matter remove your MKR tokens or leave them.

> Does Continuous Approval Voting mean endless voting?

Not necessarily. Continuous Approval Voting means that competing proposals may be introduced any time. You, a MKR holder, can vote on **any** proposal at any given time (even old ones). However, only the proposal with the most votes will be the governing proposal.

The is in contrast to a non-continuous approval voting mechanism where you may only get to vote on one of two options.

You can read all about the voting system [here](https://community-development.makerdao.com/en/learn/governance/how-voting-works/).

Comment: The proposal is a question or one of the answers for the question?